# How to make empty grid cell clickable in Asp.net Grid?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an Empty Grid View. When I click on each grid cell I want to add a pop to add items.Kindly give some idea to make my grid cell clickable.My grid view is

[image]

please help me

Comment: Why not `<td onclick="something">`? (Or are you talking Web Forms with a grid control?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little bird told me you already have labels inside. SO instead of these you can put Buttons or even better LinkButtons, and depending on how your GridView is created (from the Toolbox or code behind) you can set your Buttons to be clickable like so

```
LinkButton.Click += new EventHandler(LinkButton_Click);
```

Set their ID or CommanArgument to be something meaningful to you, and have everything done only trough C#.

BUT since you want to execute a POP (up ?) maybe the best case scenario for you is to workout how to call fancybox and then have

```
yourLabel.Attributes.Add("onClick", "Fancybox(this.id");
```

to open a pop-up.